# Cannot get braille font to work

Tags: fonts, pdftex, truetype

I want to use the eurobraille font found here: http://www.fakoo.de/braille-fonts/#achtpunkt in a latex document.

I found this script to install ttf fonts: http://devnotcorp.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/use-truetype-font-with-pdflatex/

I did not really know, what options I should use in the script, this is what I did:

```
TEXMF="/usr/local/share/texmf"
FONTFOUNDRY="linotype"
FONTNAME="HBS-8-Braille Taktil"
FONTFAMILY="braille"
FONTENC="8t"
FONTDEFENC="t1"
FONTENCFILE="T1-WGL4.enc"
```

Running the script gives me:

```
*** Finished. The truetype font HBS-8-Braille Taktil is now available as braille in LaTeX.
```

So I try this document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\begin{document}
Normal Text

{\fontfamily{braille}\selectfont 
Text in Braille%
}

\end{document}
```

And compilte it with pdflatex. I get this on the way:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/braille/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 8.
```

And well, it did not work. The Braille font is not used.
But I have no Idea what exactly went wrong.

Comment: Unless you're committed to using `pdflatex`, it might be easiest to use XeLaTeX:  put the .TTF font with your regular system fonts and just load it using `fontspec`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but using this font is trivial with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.  I installed the font as a regular font on my system and then used the following document:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\braillefont{HBS-8-Braille Taktil}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbraille}{\braillefont}
\begin{document}
\textbraille{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]